# Linq Count all items in a column

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How would I do a linq query like this
For example I want to count up all the numbers in a column and for it to return the result of them being added up

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of items in a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870/sum-of-items-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 1):

var count = mytable.Sum(t => t.myCol);

Answer (score 1):

I find the [LINQ to SQL samples site on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085.aspx) to be an excellent reference for basic questions like this.

The [Simple Sum example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737922#sumsimp) there is probably what you want:

```
// This sample uses Sum to find the total freight over all Orders.
void LinqToSqlCount03()
{
    var q =  (from o In db.Orders 
             select o.Freight).Sum()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
numbers.Sum(n => n.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
 DbContextName = dbTableName.Count(x=>x.columnName);
```