# How to sum all short elements within an array in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Taking the array:

```
var array = new short[]{4,4,5,6}
```

I want to build a linq expression that sums all this 4 array values so that the result is 19. This way i will be able to do the following comparison:

```
string a = "only5chars"
if(a.length < // the total array values length ...
```

Comment: Atleast attempt to do some research of some kind

Comment: Didn't manage to do `sum()` in a `short[]`. This is because the question.

Comment: Your question did no state you were using `short`, perhaps you should post a bit more detail and explanation

Comment: Yes I was mistaken typing the question.

Comment: In that case, every answer posted is invalidated and numerous people's time has been wasted. Just think before you post, if you were trying to answer the quest what would you think - Rant Over :)

Comment: @Arasa, your current code shouldn't compile `var array[] = new short[]{4,4,5,6}` should be `var array = new short[]{4,4,5,6}`, I have also updated my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of items in a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870/sum-of-items-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
 var array = new int[] {4, 4, 5, 6};
 var sum = array.Sum();
```

**Edit** (according to question update with `short`):

```
 var array = new short[] {4, 4, 5, 6};
 var sum = array.Select(x=> (int)x).Sum();
```

Try [HERE](http://ideone.com/zYak66).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to build a linq expression that sums all this 4 array values so
>   that the result is 19.

**EDIT:**

Since the question has now changed and now its pointing to a short type array then:

```
var array = new short[] { 4, 4, 5, 6 };
int sum = array.Select(r => (int)r).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new int[]{4,4,5,6};
var sum = array.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Real answer**

```
var array = new int[]{4,4,5,6};
array.Sum();
```

I wish stack would let me post "Let me googlge that for you" links.

**Sarcastic answer**

1. Go to [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk)
2. Search - "Sum an array C#"

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Enumerable.Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) method:

> Computes the sum of a sequence of numeric values.

Like;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var array = new int[] {4, 4, 5, 6};
      int total = array.Sum();
      Console.WriteLine(total);
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/gdBKdo).