# Calculate sum using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

```
foreach (Item item in Items)
                        {
                            Cost = Cost +
                                    item.Costs.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
                                              .FirstOrDefault()
                                              .Cost;

                        }
```

The above LINQ returns 150.

I have 4 items(1,2,3,4) with the respective Cost. I need to rewrite the above LINQ to get the correct total cost of 210.

ID--ItemID--   Cost

11 --       1   --    10

21  --    2   --  20

31   --   2   --  30

41  --    3  --   40

51  --    3  --   50

61  --   4   --  60

Can anyone please provide the modified LINQ to do so?

Modifying the LINQ as below doesnt give me the expected result --

```
foreach (Item item in Items)
                    {
                        Cost = Cost +
                                item.Costs.Sum(r => r.Cost);
                    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of items in a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870/sum-of-items-in-a-collection)

Comment: @djechlin ....Doesnt solve my problem. I already tried using the SUM function.

Comment: Are you getting a result of 360 instead of 210? Note that 360 = 150 + (150 + 60), and perhaps you can see your mistake - double counting part of your set.

Comment: @Sammy - Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure why you are messing it up by looping first and writing a query again in the loop. Do it either with a `foreach` loop or a LINQ query like this:-

```
int result = items.Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

It will give you 210 as output.