# Linq query to join two objects and calculate sum

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have two lists of objects that I need to join on `Sku` and then caluclate the `Sum` (`Qty` * `Price`). I'm not exactly sure how to do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
List<Order> orders = new List <Order> 
{ 
    new Order() { Sku = "ABC", Qty = 1 },
    new Order() { Sku = "XYZ", Qty = 2}
};

List<Cost> costs = new List <Cost> 
{ 
    new Cost() { Sku = "ABC", Price = 4.50m },
    new Cost() { Sku = "XYZ", Price = 2.25m }
};


var profit = from order in orders
             join cost in costs
             on order.Sku equals cost.Sku
             select Sum(order.Qty * cost.Price)
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: It doesn't like the last line `select Sum(order.Qty * cost.Price)`

Comment: What if there are not exactly 1:1 `Order` and `Cost` objects? I assume you're going to need some grouping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of items in a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870/sum-of-items-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your last part as follows:

```
var profit = (from order in orders
             join cost in costs
             on order.Sku equals cost.Sku
             select (order.Qty * cost.Price)).Sum();
```

Taken from here: [Stackoverflow question that answered how to sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870/sum-of-items-in-a-collection)

Comment: If this solved your issue (I saw in a snippet it worked for me), kindly mark this as answered for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response, just what I needed.